# Jquery drop down with hidden form not working after cloning

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form with a drop-down with contains names of food items and another with an input field to allow the user to input price. beneath this, i have another drop down with `class="IfNotAvailableSelectable"` which contains 3 option, with values:0,1,2.
and I have a button called "addMore" to clone everything within the div with `class="divContainer"`

the following is what I want to achieve:

1.When the user clicks on the "addmore" button, it should clone everything within the div with `class="divContainer"` and append it to the div with  `class="addMoreContent".` Of which I have been able to do successfully.

2.When the user selects  the drop-down with `class="IfNotAvailableSelectable"` and value =0, it show div with class="thenBuy" , else it should hide it.
now the problem am facing is that, whenever i  click the addmore button and select the drop down with option value 1 or 0 or 2, the original cloned div also changes with it,

so e,g: if i select value 1 ,i expect the  div with `class="thenBuy"` to hide but when on the addmore button, and select the dropdown with value = 0, it show the div with class="thenBuy" in the 1st one too,while i don't want it to.
**Please help,or if there;s a better solution  to this.Will really appreciate.Thank you**
HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  //clone
var divContainer = $(".divContainer");
var addMoreContent = $(".addMoreContent");
var addMoreBtn = $(".addMoreBtn");
  var removeItem = $(".removeItem");
  addMoreBtn.click(function () {



    divContainer.clone(true).appendTo(addMoreContent);
    

  });

  removeItem.click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  //then buy functionO(when user selects "buy alternative")
  $(document).on('change', '.IfNotAvailableSelectable', function () {


    console.log($(this).val())
    var MainNav = $(this).val();

    if (MainNav == 0) {
      $(".thenBuy").show();
    } else {
      $(".thenBuy").hide();
    }


  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- card body-->
<div class="card-body bg-white divContainer" >
   <!-- delete button -->
<button type="button" class="close col-1 bg-white removeItem" >
          <span>×</span>
        </button>
  <!-- items -->
<select class=" custom-select text-capitalize">
  <option  >Waakye </option>
  <option >Banku</option>
  <option >Plain Rice</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<!-- price -->
  <div >
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="starting price= GH¢1.00 " > 
    <!-- "min" above should be the value of the  starting price of the selected item  and placeholder strating price should be the value of the starting price of the selected item too-->
    </div>
    <br>
<!-- if item is not available --> 
<div  style="font-size: medium;" >
<select  class="custom-select  text-capitalize IfNotAvailableSelectable">
  <option value="0" >If item is not available</option> 
  <option value="1" >Remove it from my order </option>
  <option value="2">Cancel entire order</option>
</select>
<br>
<!-- then buy -->
<div class="thenBuy"   >
<div>
 <span>Then Buy</span>
<select class=" custom-select text-capitalize">
  <option >Waakye </option>
  <option >Banku</option>
  <option >Plain Rice</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<!-- price -->
  <div >
    <span>Price</span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="starting price= GH¢1.00 " > 
    <!-- "min" above should be the value of the  starting price of the selected item  and placeholder strating price should be the value of the starting price of the selected item too-->
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- end of card body -->
</div>
<br>
<div  class="addMoreContent" ></div>
<!-- onclick of add more,display the fiels here -->
<button  type="button" class="float-right btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm addMoreBtn">Add More</button> 
<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- With `$(".thenBuy")` you select all the elements with class name `thenBuy` you need to use `.parent().find(".thenBuy")`
- To let the new `.IfNotAvailableSelectable` take change effect after cloned use `.IfNotAvailableSelectable`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  //clone
  var divContainer = $(".divContainer"),
      addMoreContent = $(".addMoreContent"),
      addMoreBtn = $(".addMoreBtn"),
      removeItem = $(".removeItem");
      
  addMoreBtn.click(function () {
    divContainer.clone(true).appendTo(addMoreContent);  
    addMoreContent.find(".IfNotAvailableSelectable").last().change();  //<<<<<<<<<< trigger the change event for the last/new IfNotAvailableSelectable
  });

  removeItem.click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  //then buy functionO(when user selects "buy alternative")
  $(document).on('change', '.IfNotAvailableSelectable', function () {
    console.log($(this).val())
    var ThisSelect = $(this);  // define this
    var MainNav = ThisSelect.val();  // get this val
 
    if (MainNav == 0) {
      ThisSelect.parent().find(".thenBuy").show(); // use .parent().find
    } else {
      ThisSelect.parent().find(".thenBuy").hide(); // use .parent().find
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- card body-->
<div class="card-body bg-white divContainer" >
   <!-- delete button -->
<button type="button" class="close col-1 bg-white removeItem" >
          <span>×</span>
        </button>
  <!-- items -->
<select class=" custom-select text-capitalize">
  <option  >Waakye </option>
  <option >Banku</option>
  <option >Plain Rice</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<!-- price -->
  <div >
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="starting price= GH¢1.00 " > 
    <!-- "min" above should be the value of the  starting price of the selected item  and placeholder strating price should be the value of the starting price of the selected item too-->
    </div>
    <br>
<!-- if item is not available --> 
<div  style="font-size: medium;" >
<select  class="custom-select  text-capitalize IfNotAvailableSelectable">
  <option value="0" >If item is not available</option> 
  <option value="1" >Remove it from my order </option>
  <option value="2">Cancel entire order</option>
</select>
<br>
<!-- then buy -->
<div class="thenBuy"   >
<div>
 <span>Then Buy</span>
<select class=" custom-select text-capitalize">
  <option >Waakye </option>
  <option >Banku</option>
  <option >Plain Rice</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<!-- price -->
  <div >
    <span>Price</span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="starting price= GH¢1.00 " > 
    <!-- "min" above should be the value of the  starting price of the selected item  and placeholder strating price should be the value of the starting price of the selected item too-->
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- end of card body -->
</div>
<br>
<div  class="addMoreContent" ></div>
<!-- onclick of add more,display the fiels here -->
<button  type="button" class="float-right btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm addMoreBtn">Add More</button> 
<br>
```

Comment: i can't vote because am new here,but thank you very much,answer solved.

Comment: At least 15 rep to vote.. you'r totally welcome @theophiluskwofie .. have a great day :-)